# JHipster relation between predefined table USER and my own table

Tags: java, jhipster, jdl

I need to define new table related to predefined 'User' table.
Please, help me to write a correct JDL code for this
[entity diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK8Se.png)

I tried to write file "mytable.jh" and import :>jhipster import-jdl mytable.jh

```
entity MyTable{
    userid Long, //relation to table jhi_user
}

relationship OneToMany {
  User{id} to Mytable{userid}
}
```

and got

```
{ name: 'IllegalAssociationException',
  message: 'Relationships from User entity is not supported in the declaration between User and Mytable.',
  prototype:
   Error
```

Answer (score 12):

Basically you can't add new fields to the jhi_user table, and JDL won't let you do anything that would cause that to happen.

You *can* add a User object reference to another entity with something like

```
relationship ManyToOne {
  Mytable{userid} to User
}
```

Note there that I am *not* putting `{anything}` after `User` -- this means the `User` has no idea which `Mytable` it's associated with. If you want to "back up" from an instance of `Mytable` to an instance of `User`, you have to search from the `Mytable` side; the User won't have any fields or getters/setters related to an instance of `Mytable`.

Also note that the `userid` field is not necessarily strictly for relating the two entities. The JDL and code generation actually takes care of creating the relationships and primary/foreign keys for you. So

```
entity Car {
}

relationship ManyToOne {
  Car{user} to User
}
```

means for every `User`, there are many `Car`s, or another way of saying it is for every `Car` there is one `user` whose field name within the `Car` object will be `user`. So you'll have `Car.getUser()` method, etc.

When you define a field within an `entity` block, you're defining a property of that entity, *not* a relation -- that property is independent of all other objects in your model.

You still won't have a `User.getCars()` method though. This is not possible with current jHipster design.

Answer (score 0):

I think this [tip](https://jhipster.github.io/tips/022_tip_registering_user_with_additional_information.html) in the jhipster doc might help you, I never looked at it, but a mate did this during my project I'm crrently working on. Hope this helps. You can always ask [Paul-Etienne](https://github.com/Paul-Etienne) for further information, he will gladly help.

Comment: The question is about putting a relation to User table using JDL. It is not about how to do it in java.

Comment: I don't see how it is relevant